# Calling a function in a loopback model.js file from a regular JS file

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, loopback

I am trying to call a function in loopback model.js file called `models/customerProfile.js` from a JS file `server/script/myScripts.js` but I am getting this error:

> Unhandled error for request GET /api/CustomerProfiles/verifyCustomer?id=38733: TypeError: myScripts.verifyCustomerProfile is not a function

I want to keep all my generic functions in this myScripts file and call them from my model.js files.

I did the following in my customerProfile.js model file to include the script:

```
var myScripts = require('../../server/script/myScripts');
```

then in my code I referenced it as follows:

```
myScripts.functionName();
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you export your functions ?

### myScripts.js

Try this one :

```
module.exports = {

functionName : function() {
 // Your code
},

functionName2 : function() {
 // some code
},

// You can add more functions

}
```

Comment: module.exports = function (app) {

    verifyCustomerProfile = function(id){
        console.log("I am here");
    }   
}

This is the sample of the function in the myScripts.js file. I am trying to use this function in my customerProfile.js model.